# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, error-handling, entity-framework-6

In the code for my windows service I have a try catch block.
When I run a unit test on my development machine on a the database , the unit test passes.

When the service runs on the production server with the same database, an error occurs and two events appear in the Windows Event log.

```
EventType clr20r3, P1 MKG.XPREFLIGHT.servicehost.exe, P2 2.0.62.0, 
P3 574a1457, P4 mscorlib, P5 4.0.0.0, P6 53b50a71, P7 3e5, P8 10d, 
P9 system.formatexception, P10 NIL.
```

and

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1026
Date:       29/05/2016
Time:       8:03:54 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   SERVERX1
Description:
Application: MKG.XPREFLIGHT.ServiceHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[])
   at MKG.XPREFLIGHT.Engine.FlightEngine.ParseCommand(MKG.ServiceData.EngineCommandQueue)
   at MKG.XPREFLIGHT.Engine.FlightEngine.TakeCommands()
   at MKG.XPREFLIGHT.Engine.FlightEngine.PollingProc(System.Object)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(System.Object)
```

I isolated the area of code that the error occurs in, but since the unit test passes I cannot see why the error occurs.

The error is repeatable although the fault does not occur in the same place the first time the process runs after a server reboot.

The code is within a Try Catch block, however it does not get caught.  Instead the service stops with errors in the windows event log.

How can I troubleshoot this?
[update]

the code that fails is

```
public Job GetDeepJobWithUploadInfo(int jobId)
{
 // if I throw an error here it is caught
    Job job = null;

    using (var connect = MakeConnect())
    {

        job =
            connect.job.AsNoTracking()
                .Include(
                    j =>
                        j.VivUpload.Select(
                            u =>
                                u.VivSplitUpload.Select(
                                    s =>
                                        s.VivSplitProfile.Select(
                                            p => p.VivSplitLog.Select(l => l.VivSplitLogType)))))
                .Include(j => j.VivUpload.Select(u => u.VivSplitUpload.Select(s => s.VivSplitProfile)))
                .Include(j => j.JobTag)
                .SingleOrDefault(j => j.JobID == jobId);
    }
     // never gets to here in production, but does get here in unit test
    return job;
}
```

I have tried running the custom tool on the edmx to regenerate the Entity Framework classes.

Comment: try showing the code might help don't you think ?

Comment: The problem was caused by an error in my error handler.  It seemed that the problem was occurring in GetDeepJobWithUploadInfo because this was running on a separate thread.

Comment: You can add [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handler and show more details about exception. For type [TargetInvocationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can look on InnerException for more details.